# How to add multiple .nc files to a rasterStack in R

Tags: r

I am trying to create a large rasterStack in R. I have 255 .nc files in a directory. So far I have the following code:

```
files = list.files(pattern = "*.nc")
st<- stack()

for (i in 1:length(files)) {
    r<-raster(files[i], level = 1, crs = newproj, varname = "SWE" )
    st<- addLayer(r)
}
```

When I run the code outside of a for loop with only one file, it works fine, but when I run it with the for loop (trying to add every file to the stack, I get this error:

Error in sapply(x, fromDisk) & sapply(x, inMemory) : 
  operations are possible only for numeric, logical or complex types

If someone could explain the error to me and where I am going wrong, that would be awesome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: replace `st<- addLayer(r)` with `st<- addLayer(st, r)`.